# How Do I Pubish Dependency Jars and POM To A New Repository?

Tags: gradle

We are switching maven repos to a private one.

I need to populate the new repo with all the transitive dependencies from my project with their original poms and any javadoc or source classifier artifacts.

I can't use replication because I only want a sub-set from the original repository (also the jars are actually coming from a mix of repositories).

The company wants it completely private and doesn't want to use mirroring.

When I use the gradle maven-publish task it generates its own pom and doesn't use the existing pom.

This will end up copying some of maven central.

The project should build using only this repo.

Comment: I assume the new repository will at least mirror maven-central? Otherwise, you will also need to upload manually everything else, like Spring?

Comment: So any project you migrate will need to be built using this private repository only?

Comment: Updated question to answer the comments above. i.e. it will copy some of maven central and will upload things like spring to it. This project should build from this private repo only.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle publication is about publishing the project you are working on, not its transitive dependencies.

I would recommend the following strategy for creating your private repository:

1. Configure it for mirroring
2. White list the dependencies that are allowed

This will save you the trouble of having to re-upload each and every transitive in your dependency graph.

If that's really not an option, have a look at the [Maven `deploy:deploy-file` Mojo](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html) which will allow you to specify the Maven POM file, the matching artifact and upload that to a remote repository.